# npm: script in package.json, what to do with white spaces

Tags: json, shell, npm, package.json

Trying to make this work, in a package.json file

```
"zip": "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a -tzip -mx9 yes.zip folder\\*"
```

But it doesn't work due to

```
'C:\Program\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I've tried this with identical non-working results

```
"zip": "C:\\Program\\ Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a -tzip -mx9 yes.zip folder\\*"
"zip": "\"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a -tzip -mx9 yes.zip folder\\*\""
"zip": "\"C:\\Program\\ Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a -tzip -mx9 yes.zip folder\\*\""
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Solved by adding the quotes in the correct position

```
"zip": "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a -tzip -mx9 yes.zip folder\\*"
```